# Invoking a javascript function using Webbrowser tag is stopping my UI thread

Tags: c#, javascript, multithreading, windows-phone-8

I am invoking a Javascript function using Webbrowser in Windows Phone 8.

```
 browserControl.InvokeScript(funtionName, args);
```

This javascipt function is internally calling a service to fetch the data, during the javascript call i am showing ProgressIndicator.

**But i am not able to see ProgressIndicator because javascript call is stopping UI thread.**

**This problem may because of Javascript function and my UI thread is running in same thread.** So i tried my move Javascript function call to Background thread, but it failed saying "Invalid cross thread Access"

**Can any please suggest how can i overcome this problem?**

**Edit:**

My progress indicator code:

```
public void ActivateProgressIndicator(this PhoneApplicationPage currentPage, string progressIndicatorText)
        {
            ProgressIndicator progressIndicator = new ProgressIndicator();
            progressIndicator.Text = progressIndicatorText;
            progressIndicator.IsVisible = true;
            progressIndicator.IsIndeterminate = true;
            SystemTray.SetProgressIndicator(currentPage, progressIndicator);
        }
```

My JS fucnction is calling a WCF rest service internally, this function call will take 30 seconds 1 minute. And i am JS code to Background thread like below:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
            {
                WebBrowser browserControl = new WebBrowser();
                browserControl.IsScriptEnabled = true;
                browserControl.Navigate(new Uri("/WebAssets/Main.html", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

                browserControl.InvokeScript("RetrieveMultiple",
                                                         "http://some.service.net/",
                                                         "Plain",
                                                         "arg1",
                                                         "arg2",
                                                         "arg3");
            });
```

I am getting Invalid cross thread error while i am creating the webbrowser control.

Comment: Could you add some relevant code? How is your ProgressIndicator wired up? What is your JavaScript function doing and how long does it normally take? How did you try to move the JS call to the background, and what line caused the invalid cross-thread access error?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Thomas, I have edited my Question can you please look in to my question now.